# Algorithm to calculate the count of numbers with a digit sum less than or equal to 'x' within a given range

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, math

I am looking for a Python algorithm that can efficiently count the number of integers between 1 and `n` whose digit sum is less than or equal to a given value `x`. In my case, `n` can reach values up to 10^12.

For example, if `n` is 112 and `x` is 5, the algorithm should return the count of integers between 0 and 112 (inclusive) whose digit sum is less than or equal to 5.

This function provides the correct solution for any input. However, it is highly inefficient when using large ranges since it loops through every number and calculates its digit sum.

```
def digitsums_lower_than_x(x, n):
    digit_sum = lambda y: sum(int(digit) for digit in str(y))
    return sum(1 for i in range(1, n+1) if digit_sum(i) <= x)+1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your example: "if x is 112 and ... between 0 and 100 (inclusive)". Why 100 when x is 112? Also, how big can n be?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: The function is sort of correct, but x and n are wrongly labeled. (and for x=1000, n=30 the answer is 1001 since both ends of the range 0...x are included).

Comment: @George is the correct rule "between 1 and `x`" (per the first paragraph) or "between 0 and `x`" (per the second)?

Comment: Hah, I didn't notice the ambiguity. The slow python program implicitly includes 0 as a solution, so the votes are 2-1 in favor of 0...x rather than 1...x.

Comment: @George are you sure? Note that you have `range(1,n+1)` and `<=x`. Shouldn't it be `range(1,x+1)` and `<=n` ?

Comment: @George the meaning of `n` and `x` are opposite in the program compared to the prose in the question.

Comment: @Paul Hankin Oh, I'm so sorry... That was stupid. Yeah, I meant n as range and x as the digit sum limit.

Comment: You forgot to also fix the 0-vs-1 issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `DS(n, x)` be the number of integers in the range `0`...`x` (inclusive) with digit sum at most `n`.

If the top digit of `x` is `D`, then for each `d` from `0` to `min(D, n)`, count numbers of the same length as `x` but with the top digit `d`. This transforms the problem of computing `DS(n, x)` into up to 10 problems of computing `DS(n-d, x')` where `x'` is either `x` with the top digit removed, or a number that's one less than a power of 10 and has length one less than `x`. This gives you an O(min(n, log x) * log x) solution if you're careful not to recompute things twice (ie: the cases where `x'` is one less than a power of 10).

For example, to compute DS(5, 112):

```
DS(5, 112) = 3-digit solutions starting 0 + 3-digit solutions starting 1
DS(5, 112) = DS(5, 99) + DS(4, 12)

DS(5, 99) = 2-digit solutions starting with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
          = DS(5, 9) + DS(4, 9) + DS(3, 9) + DS(2, 9) + DS(1, 9) + DS(0, 9)
          = 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 21 

DS(4, 12) = 2-digit solutions starting with 0 + solutions starting with 1
          = DS(4, 9) + DS(3, 2)
          = 5 + 3 = 8
```

So DS(5, 112) = 21 + 8 = 29

Here's an example program (that's not perfect since it does some O(log x) work in each step, but it's unlikely to matter).

```
def D(x, n, cache):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return min(n, int(x[0]))+1
    if (x, n) not in cache:
        top = int(x[0])
        nines = '9' * (len(x) - 1)
        cache[x, n] = sum(D(nines if d < top else x[1:], n-d, cache)
                          for d in range(min(n, top)+1))
    return cache[x, n]

def DS(x, n):
    return D(str(x), n, dict())

print(DS(112, 5))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an efficient algorithm by considering the possible digit sums for each position in the numbers.

```
def count_numbers_with_digit_sum(x, n):
    def count_helper(pos, remaining_sum):
        if pos == 0:
            return 1 if remaining_sum >= 0 else 0

        count = 0
        for digit in range(10):
            count += count_helper(pos - 1, remaining_sum - digit)

        return count

    return count_helper(len(str(x)), n)

# Example usage:
x = 112
n = 5
result = count_numbers_with_digit_sum(x, n)
print(result)
```

Comment: This isn't correct. For example that makes it obvious, try it with `x=10, n=5`. The result is 21, which is obviously incorrect - the correct result cannot possibly be greater than `x`.